# Preferred port 9515 not available, will use: 54724 and when it's sending a request to create session on this port it fails

Tags: karate

In my Karate framework, I need to open the browser and hit the url. For me I can see only blank window and in logs I am getting following error.

```
14:17:05.481 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] DEBUG com.intuit.karate.shell.Command - found / verified free local port: 54724
14:17:05.483 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] WARN c.intuit.karate.driver.DriverOptions - preferred port 9515 not available, will use: 54724
```

Also, I added port 9515 in my machine and again same issue like browser opened without hitting url. New logs are

```
19:08:40.064 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] ERROR com.intuit.karate - java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out, http call failed after 30010 milliseconds for URL: http://localhost:9515/session
19:08:40.066 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] ERROR com.intuit.karate - http request failed:
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
19:08:40.092 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] ERROR com.intuit.karate - driver config / start failed:
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out, options: {type=chromedriver, timeout=60000, target=null}
com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: 
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `chromedriver` instances were not shut down properly, make sure you kill them all by using the task-manager, etc.

This also sounds like you don't have admin / permissions, typical on Windows. If still stuck, follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue